# Search a pattern in file and replace another pattern in the same line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I would like to search for a pattern in bunch of source files. The pattern should act as a marker. If the pattern is found, I would like to process that line by performing a substitution of another string

**For example:**

```
Private const String myTestString = @"VAL15"; // STRING—REPLACE-VAL##
```

Here, I want to search my source file for pattern `STRING—REPLACE-VAL` and then replace `VAL15` with `VAL20` in same.

**Output:**

```
private const String myTestString = @"VAL20"; // STRING—REPLACE-VAL##
```

Tried below command but not working as expected.

```
sed -i  '/,STRING—REPLACE-VAL##/ {; s/,VAL15,/,VAL20,/;}' myTestFile.cpp
```

**Question:** Is it possible to search for `STRING—REPLACE-VAL##` and then search for matching pattern `@"VAL`??" in same line and replace 15 by 20.

`sed` supports search & replacing the same pattern very easily but not sure if `sed` supports to search pattern but replace another string in the matching line?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You were very close :

```
sed -i '/STRING—REPLACE-VAL##/{s/VAL15/VAL20/}' myTestFile.cpp
```

In your original you were trying to replace `",VAL15,"` but this string is not in the line (the commas). Furthermore, the same occurs for your search string `",STRING—REPLACE-VAL##"`.

It also occured to me that the first hyphen between `STRING` and `REPLACE` is an em-dash and not a standard `-`, maybe this is another problem. Make sure that the string is exactly the same. If you are not sure about the dashes, you could use

```
sed -i '/STRING.REPLACE.VAL##/{s/VAL15/VAL20/}' myTestFile.cpp
```

and to answer your question, yes you can try to do multiple matches in the following way:

**`sed`:**

```
sed -i '/STRING.REPLACE.VAL##/{ /@"VAL/ { s/VAL15/VAL20/ } }' myTestFile.cpp
```

**`awk`:**

```
awk '/STRING.REPLACE.VAL##/&&/@"VAL/{sub("VAL15","VAL20")}1'  myTestFile.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

The search pattern in the attempt includes many superfluous/erronious commas -- and that is the reason that the match was failing.  Patterns and searches are delimited by default with the `/` character. (Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise it is a good idea to stick with `/` for readability.)

One thing to be careful of is to make sure that your word is exactly matched... and that *VAL15**2*** (for example) is not matched.  You can enclose *VAL15* within `\<` and `\>` to match the word boundary.

Also, wrapping parentheses are not required after the match pattern.

```
sed -i '/STRING—REPLACE-VAL##/ s/\<VAL15\>/VAL20/' myTestFile.cpp
```

@kvantour noted that you specified a special em  dash character `—` in the match that is non-ascii & suggested ways to work around this -- but we can also use a trick to exactly match what you want and make that aspect stand out more (note: sh/bash assumed as the shell -- note the careful use of quoting).

```
sed -i "/STRING$(printf '\342\200\224')REPLACE-VAL##/ s/\<VAL15\>/VAL20/" myTestFile.cpp
```

Or to match hyphen and em dash in both places:

```
emdash=$(printf '\342\200\224')
sed -i "/STRING[-$emdash]REPLACE[-$emdash]VAL##/ s/\<VAL15\>/VAL20/" myTestFile.cpp
```

We can expand on this further on this to include the en dash as well -- left as an exercise for the reader.  To help with that exercise, here is how I was able to decode your em dash char:

```
echo '—' | od -c
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed you could just do

```
sed -i '/STRING—REPLACE-VAL##/s/VAL15/VAL20/' myTestFile.cpp
```